# Turning the `match` command on and off

Tags: highlight, whitespace

I found this useful setting form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617059/showing-trailing-spaces-in-vim) post, which highlights trailing whitespaces :

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=grey guibg=grey
noremap <F10> :match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/<CR>
```

This works when I tap F10 but I also want the highlighting to **go away** when I tap F10 again.
Typing `:match` works but I was wondering if this could be done from this keymap itself. I tried putting `!` after `match` but that is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a List of all matches previously defined for the current window with the `getmatches()` function. By using an `<expr>` mapping, you can dynamically set a mapping based on the size of the List returned by `getmatches()` with a conditional expression.

---

Conditional expressions in Vimscript (often called ternary expressions in other languages) take the following form:

```
a ? b : c
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are expressions. If `a` evaluates to `true`, then the conditional expression as a whole evaluates to `b`, otherwise, it evaluates to `c`.

The following expression evaluates to `':match<CR>'` if the length of the List returned by `getmatches()` is greater than zero, otherwise it will evaluate to `':match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/<CR>'`.

```
len(getmatches()) > 0 ? ':match<CR>' : ':match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/<CR>'
```

---

Using an `<expr>` mapping allows you to evaluate an expression to determine the function of the mapping, rather than a static value. The result of the expression should be a string representation of the desired Ex commands.

---

So, putting our conditional expression together with our `<expr>` mapping, we can do the following:

```
noremap <expr> <F10> len(getmatches()) > 0 ? ':match<CR>' : ':match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/<CR>'
```

---

Relevant help:

```
:h :map-<expr>
:h getmatches()
```